# Google Spreadsheet Formula for Weekend Dates

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, date, google-spreadsheets

In Google Sheets, what formula can I use to create a list of weekend dates where each row shows the next upcoming Sat/Sun as follows:

```
05/18/2019 - 05/19/2019
05/25/2019 - 05/26/2019
06/01/2019 - 06/02/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **A1** enter:

```
=TEXT(date(2019,5,18)+7*(row()-1),"mm/dd/yyyy") & "-" & text(date(2019,5,19)+7*(row()-1),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

and copy downwards.

[image]

Similar to Excel.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great and teaches me a lot about how to create variations of this as needed in the future.